# Unable to convert value of type '(FIRUser, _) -> ()' to expected argument type for 'FIRAuthResultCallBack' Error

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am a beginner using Swift 3
I am receiving the error: cannot convert value of type '(FIRUser, _) -> ()' to expected argument type for 'FIRAuthResultCallBack?'

what is this error and how can i fix it?

```
func handleRegister() {

    guard let email = emailTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextfield.text else{
        print("Invalid Entry to Form")
        return
    }

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user: FIRUser, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(123456)
            return
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls replace your code with:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, err) in
       if error != nil 
       {
            print(123456)
            return
       }
})
```